# Twilio throws fatal error in php 7.x

Tags: twilio-php

I"m getting the following error in my production server, I gave the maximum possible permission for this `wp-content` directory and I still get this error, can you please assist ?

> PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/Rest/.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio.php on
>   line 9, PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Services_Twilio_Rest_'
>   not found in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/Resource.php:47\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/Rest/Account.php(23):
>   Services_Twilio_Resource->setupSubresources('applications',
>   'available_phone...', 'outgoing_caller...', 'calls', 'conferences',
>   'incoming_phone_...', 'notifications', 'outgoing_caller...',
>   'recordings', 'sms_messages', 'short_codes', 'transcriptions',
>   'connect_apps', 'authorized_conn...', 'usage_records',
>   'usage_triggers', 'queues')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/Resource.php(25):
>   Services_Twilio_Rest_Account->init(Object(Services_Twilio),
>   '/2010-04-01/Acc...')\n#2
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(39):
>   Services_Twilio_Resource->__construct(Object(Services_Twilio),
>   '/2010-04-01/Acc...')\n#3
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio.php(73):
>   Services_Twilio_ListResource->get('AC2ab0e6e0b in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/text-my-app/Services/Twilio/Resource.php
>   on line 47, referer:

Comment: Please format the error message by using the code formatting button.